# why VS tell me change signature for this action in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2017

for this Action in C# asp.net mvc the VS show me a bubble yellow that change signature. I use VS 2017.

why show me this error

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
{
    AdminLoginViewModel loginModel = new AdminLoginViewModel();
    loginModel.Email = string.Empty;
    loginModel.Password = null;
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

[the light bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8YHz.png)

[after click on light bubble show me this window. whats does means?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR5Um.png)

have any idea?

Comment: It's just a helper, not a recommendation/error.

Comment: It shows it on every method, it is not a warning, but refactoring action

Comment: Why do I need to refactoring the code? Has the action a problem?

Comment: No, it's not a problem. It's merely something that shows up to assist you with changing the signature if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an error, this is the classic Light Bulb that is present starting from Visual Studio 2015, a feature which show you some suggestions based on the context.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn872466.aspx